# How to create a graphql schema that can be searched on different fields?

Tags: scala, graphql, sangria

I'm testing out [sangria](http://sangria-graphql.org/) to build a graphql/relay server. I have a very simple User class:

```
case class User(
  id: Int,
  username: String,
  gender: Gender.Value)
```

I want to allow queries by either ID or username. I have created a schema that allows this, but the fields have different names:

```
val Query = ObjectType(
  "Query", fields[UserRepo, Unit](
    Field("user", OptionType(User),
      arguments = ID :: Nil,
      resolve = ctx => ctx.ctx.getUser(ctx arg ID)),
    Field("userByUsername", OptionType(User),
      arguments = Username :: Nil,
      resolve = ctx => ctx.ctx.getUserByUsername(ctx arg Username))
  ))
```

Unfortunately, I need to query these with different fields names, `user` and `userByUsername`, e.g.:

```
curl -G localhost:8080/graphql     
  --data-urlencode 'query={userByUsername(username: "Leia Skywalker") {id, username, gender}}'
```

or

```
curl -G localhost:8080/graph    
  --data-urlencode "query={user(id: 1025) {id, username, gender}}"
```

How can I create a schema that allows a single field called `user` to be queried on either ID or username? E.g. both of the following should return the same user object:

```
curl -G localhost:8080/graphql     
  --data-urlencode 'query={user(username: "Leia Skywalker") {id, username, gender}}'
```

or

```
curl -G localhost:8080/graph    
  --data-urlencode "query={user(id: 1025) {id, username, gender}}"
```

Answer (score 3):

I finally worked it out:

```
val ID = Argument("id", OptionInputType(IntType), description = "id of the user")
val Username = Argument("username", OptionInputType(StringType), description = "username of the user")

val Query = ObjectType(
  "Query", fields[UserRepo, Unit](
    Field("user", OptionType(User),
      arguments = List(ID, Username),
      resolve = ctx => ctx.ctx.getUser(ctx.argOpt(ID), ctx.argOpt(Username)))
  ))
```

And `getUser` looks like:

```
def getUser(id: Option[Int], username: Option[String]): Option[User] = {

  if (id.isEmpty && username.isEmpty) {
    None
  }
  else {
    id.flatMap(i => users.find(_.id == i))
      .orElse(username.flatMap(u => users.find(_.username == u)))
  }
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that right now, relay will fail with a validation error if it is given a schema like this. See https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/112